# Listen for message written to console node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a good way of setting up an event in node to watch for when something is written to the console?  I would like something like watches the console and reacts accordingly if a particular message was written to it.  Is there a better way to do that besides create a function that wraps `console.log` and the wrapper function performs the action I need?
is there anything better than this?  This isn't all that feasible, and it'd be much easier to just listen for an onConsole event

```
function logWrapper(msg,fn){
   console.log(msg)
   fn();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any events at all in [the API documentation for `console`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html), which surprised me to be truthful.

If this is for your own code, a wrapper function is the way to go.

If you need to also listen in on messages from other code, you *could* try replacing `log`:

```
var realLog = console.log;
console.log = function() {
    // ...your code...

    // Pass off to the real one
    return realLog.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

...but I'd avoid that if you reasonably can.

Comment: Hi Crowder..i am curious to know why is it good to avoid this kind of watch. For the advantage of larger audience can you write a line or two please.

Comment: @EshwarPrasadYaddanapudi: Primarily because it involves modifying an object (`console`) that our code doesn't own. Something to stay away from when possible.